# How to change color of elements with angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

How can I change color of elements using css classes with angular js. I read some stuff online but somehow I am missing something as it does not work for me.

My js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ynko3ct3/1/

Code:

```
<p class="change-background-color">No difference!</p>
 <form>
 <div class="form-group">
      <label>Header color</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text"  ng-model="Headercolor" placeholder="#f00">
    </div>
    </form>
```

css

```
.change-background-color { background-color: {{Headercolor}}; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check also this link : [PLUNKER DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/tMlVSiNKbSXk9w5vJnyD?p=preview)

need to use `ng-style="yourVariableName"` in your `<p></p>` tag and call a function on change of input field to set input field color for `<p></p>` tag.

In html:

```
<p ng-style="backColor">this is a simple background color seter</p>
<input ng-model="headerColor" ng-change="setColor()">
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.headerColor = '#cd0a0a';
  $scope.backColor = {'background-color':$scope.headerColor};
  $scope.setColor = function() {
    $scope.backColor = {'background-color':$scope.headerColor};
  };
```

Comment: Can I use the same from a directive?

Comment: yep, you can from a directive

Answer (score 4):

Please check the updated fddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ynko3ct3/2/

You should use `ng-style` directive to change style attribute in HTML, **not in CSS** like this:

```
<p class="change-background-color" ng-style="{'background-color':Headercolor}">
  No difference!
</p>
```

Comment: Is there a way where I don’t have to change a lot in HTML. The problem is that there are many elements like links and I don’t want to go and add ng-style everywhere

Comment: Angular v1.x can affect your HTML, templates - only if you change them accordingly. but never your CSS